# nid for custom form module

Tags: 7, nodes

I have created a custom module(a simple form) in `drupal 7` using  https://www.drupal.org/node/717722 , i have successfully installed newly created module and able to save the form data. But i need an `nid` for this module which is being use by other module to perform series of tasks, i have been searching a lot about how can i found the `nid` of custom module ,but none of solution worked , also i have searched in the database table , other contents like `webform` , `basic page` and `articles` are there in database with there nid's but the newly created module's nid is not there ,can any one please help how can i find the `nid` of custom module and if there is no such `nid` then how can i set and `nid` for newly created module.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms don't have nid. Only nodes are having nid (node_id) in drupal. If you are displaying the form on any node page, suppose on `http://example.com/node/123`. Here 123 would be the node id and you can fetch it in form by

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
}
```

And if you want this `$nid` to be passed through different form states, add this as form field

```
$form['nid'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => $nid);
```

Comment: thank u for your solution , but i added your first code (in my_module.module file)  to fetch nid , it gives me error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\Drupal_maestro\sites\all\modules\my_module\my_module.module on line 50`

Comment: there was a ) missing for if syntax. Now do the same and check

Comment: thanks for quick reply, i have done changes in code, but it doesn't give me the nid value , the code is as below               `global $nid;
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
   $nid = arg(1);
}
$form['nid'] = array(
'#title'=>t('nid'),
'#type' => 'value',
 '#value' => $nid
 );
`

Comment: remove global $nid; that is nothing .. and can you tell me the URL which you are on ? also can you again read my answer and tell me what do you want to achieve now ?

Comment: so you mean to say if there is nid in url then only your code gives the value. My url is the url of my module and there is no nid in that,if i would have the url with nid, then what's the point to print it.what i want to achieve now is just the nid of my custom module, also do i need to set it manually or it will be generated.

Comment: @alex12 I already told you that there can't be any nid for your module. Better go through drupal basics before developing any custom module. https://www.drupal.org/documentation

Comment: thanks, ys i have studied about drupal nid, there is nid for modules like content type ,for every form created with the help of web form,so how can i set the nid for my module,i need it only thanks.

Comment: Again .. Nid can be set for nodes only, yes webforms have nid. But your module can never have a nid. Thanks

Comment: ok thanks...but still not getting the reason why a custom module can not have a nid while other modules like webform can have.

Comment: what is not clear or not helpful here which makes you to downvote the question, if some one doesn't know the answer does it mean that the question is not helpful or not clear, can you reply please.??

Comment: Nid = (node id) sir :( . Only for nodes, and if you created an article and if it is having nid = 1, then it is not a module. Modules are made to create some new functionality, forms, alter some hooks, etc. In your module do whatever your task is, why NID is needed for module ? Is it throwing some error, like nid is required for this module to work. Worst part is  still you're saying what is not clear :( and I don't know the answer. I am working in drupal only from past 3.5 years, you think I don't know the answer ?

Comment: I know answer to almost each and every question asked on this site, reason for not answering all is only time :).  If you face any other problem Alex ask me, I'll answer your questions. Hope you got my point and will not say again I require nid for my custom module. You need to read some drupal basics. You seem new to Drupal. Welcome, we're here to assist you. :)

Comment: apologize for irrelevant comments, the question is a part of long question,i am working on `maestro` module with webforms and creating an intermediate module which can accept custom forms(which are there in my custom module) instead of webform, since it is not appropriate to post whole question here, will post another question for that. Again i appreciate your time.

Comment: please follow the link for question which uses this question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154207/use-custom-forms-instead-of-web-form-and-content-type-in-maestro-drupal

Answer (score 0):

As [Himanshu-Pathak](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/17883/himanshu-pathak) said `nid` is for node not a module. You have to let us know what you are going to do, but when you said you want to get the id of nodes, so you want to do some processing on nodes. I recommend you to do this action using [hook_node_load](http://hook_node_load) or [hook_node_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) or [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) . These functions are called when a node is loaded, so you can get its ID and do anything you want in there (like displaying your form)

Comment: thanks for reply, as the question states i have a custom module ,now i need nid of that module, for that do i need to create a node in that model or it will generate a unique nid for every module automatically, like i have seen some for content type , articles etc.

Comment: Every module is determined by its name. We would help you better if you let us know what exactly you are going  to do. `nid` means Node ID, not module ID

Comment: thanks, i want a module which is having a nid,can it be achieve by creating a module with node?, or by creating  a node which has the module?, i am new to drupal so not sure which one is feasible and can be implement.

Comment: @alex12 `nid` is short for "node ID". It refers to the numeric identifier assigned to each piece of content (node) created on the site. It's not something a module can "have" as such. The Webform module attaches extra functionality to the node system, but Webforms are nodes, which is why they have a `nid`. The Webform module cannot have a `nid` itself. I think the confusion is being caused by an over- and/or incorrect use of the term "module". A module is a collection of code files used to extend Drupal in some way. Its only identifier is its name

Comment: @Drupalist hope you can help him :)