# Use custom forms instead of web-form and content type in Maestro drupal

Tags: 7

There is a requirement that we can't use `content type` and `webforms` with `maestro`, and have to use a custom form module (a newly created module having a simple form).

1. Normally maestro module uses `content type`, so first we create a `content type` and then we can use it in  `content type task`, if we go `content type task`->edit->`select a content type for this task`, we can see the list of all created content types here.
2. Similarly, if we don't want to use `content type` we have another option,that is to use `web form`, for that we will be needed another module called `maestro_webform_task`,here first we need to create a `web form` using `webform module` and then we will create a `web form task`  in `template`, if we follow the same path  i.e. `web form task`->edit->`select a webform to use for this task`, we will see the list of all `webforms` in select list.

here in 2. `nid` of created webform is passed to intermediate module `maestro_webform_task` and it's job is to make the webform available to select in select list of webform task.

As discussed instead of `content type` and `webform` I have a custom module(it contains a simple form ) and i want to use the form of that module to be available in the `webform task` select list.

How can I achieve this, or is there a module in Druapl 7 which allow me to do this?

Comment: This one seems quite convincing :). I'll have a look soon.